# How much time to re-mine blockchain at current hashpower?

Tags: mining-hardware, hashpower

It has taken 9 and half years to mine all blocks averaging 1 per 10 minutes.

How long would it take to re-mine all current blocks at current hashing power?

Comment: To answer this question as I understand it, one would have to sum over all published blocks the number of hashes computed (real, or approximated from difficulty of that block), divide this by the latest hashpower, and multiply this by 10 minutes (this could be refined but is IMHO a good enough approximation).

Answer (score 1):

it would take approximately 9,5 years because it does not matter how many hash-power you have. the mining-difficulty will be adjusted so that in average a new block is still mined every 10minutes also if you get much more hash-power.

Comment: I think the OP did not mean "re-hash with the normal rules" (to which would answer would be fine) but "produce the same amount of computation as was needed to compute the whole blockchain, but with a constant technology and hashrate, the ones observable today". The expected answer is thus much smaller.